# How can I use a WHERE clause in GridView control?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I want to create a where clause so that I can get the values from the database to the gridview with some particular id which I have stored in ViewState on page load. Where clause is marked in stars in the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" Width="100%"
                EmptyDataText="--- No records yet. ---" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="5"
                EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#888581" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Size="14px" EmptyDataRowStyle-Height="30px"
                EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Italic="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E2E2E2"
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pager">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RowSelector" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />


                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Title FROM Table **WHERE AnotherID=@AnotherID** ORDER BY ID">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this methord to bind your gridview

```
protected void BindGridview(int anotherid)
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
   {
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title FROM Table WHERE AnotherID='"+anotherid+"' ORDER BY ID", con);
      SqlDataAdapter da*emphasized text* = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(ds);
      con.Close();
      gvView.DataSource = ds;
      gvView.DataBind();
}
```

if you want to bind with sqldatasource

```
    SqlDataSource SqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
    SqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
    SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, Title FROM Table WHERE AnotherID='"+anotherid+"' ORDER BY ID";
    gvView.DataSource = SqlDataSource;
    gvView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString  %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Title FROM Table WHERE WHERE [AnotherID] = '" + @anotherid + "' ORDER BY ID ">
       <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%# ViewState("ViewStateID") %>' Name="anotherid" Type="Int32" />
       </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

1. Create parameter from ViewState
2. Include parameter name with "@"+paramterName in select command.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. :-) Got my solution by trying the procedure posted by Midhun